# What would be a more formal way of saying 'I thoroughly enjoy this line of work'?

Tags: synonyms, formality

I am trying to find a synonym for 'thoroughly enjoy' in this particular context, for a motivation letter. Is there a better way to express it other than saying 'I find this line of work thrilling', I am not sure whether it sounds formal enough.
Thank you for the help !

Comment: Define *formal* and *formal enough*.

Answer (score 3):

I think "thoroughly enjoy" is already more than formal enough for any use where discussing your own reaction is appropriate.

Any phrasing more formal ("this profession is a source of pleasure to many of its participants, including myself") would border on parody.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what a motivation letter is or how formal it is supposed to be, "thoroughly enjoy" sounds fine if it's a cover letter for a job application although you might want to go into more detail as to why you enjoy it.

In writing for my own job applications I talked about particular aspects of the work using words like "fascinating", "satisfying" to express that I enjoy the work overall. Because my applications were for jobs in combination with higher education I used "enjoy" in the context of learning about the subject and furthering my career.